# Calculate, Sort and rearrange components

Tags: python, python-2.7

My import list is a list with different components. The scripts calculates how many same components there  are.
I'm trying to sort them and put "part" in front of them.

Code:

```
Using code from @MagunRa
```

Input File (new):

```
Part                    Value          Package               Library                                Position (mm)         Orientation
C1       100n                              C0402             rcl              (117.65 40.75)        R270
C2       100n                              C0603             rcl              (-48.26 53.34)        R0
C3       1u                                C0402             rcl              (-50.8 78.74)         R0
C4       1u                                C0402             rcl              (9 63.1)              R270
C5       10n-1%                            C0402             rcl              (81.55 39.65)         R270
C6       100n                              C0603             rcl              (-54.61 53.34)        R0
C7       100n                              C0402             rcl              (-60.96 53.34)        R0
C8       100n                              C0603             rcl              (-67.31 53.34)        R0
C9       100n                              C0603             rcl              (-73.66 53.34)        R0
C10      100n                              C0402             rcl              (117.8 50.55)         R270
C11      100n                              C0603             rcl              (-17.78 58.42)        R0
C12      100n                              C0603             rcl              (-24.13 58.42)        R0
C13      1u                                C0402             rcl              (80.35 45.95)         R0
C14      100n                              C0402             rcl              (78.15 52.75)         R0
C15      1u                                C0402             rcl              (81.5 44.1)           R90
C16      10u                               C0402             rcl              (79.25 40.75)         R270
C17      22u                               C0603             rcl              (-59.69 63.5)         R0
C18      100n                              C0603             rcl              (-36.83 58.42)        R0
C19      100n                              C0603             rcl              (-43.18 58.42)        R0
C20      100n                              C0603             rcl              (-49.53 58.42)        R0
C21      100u                              A/3216-18R        rcl              (-60.96 40.64)        R0
C22      100n                              C0402             rcl              (-55.88 58.42)        R0
C23      10n                               C0402             rcl              (-64.77 63.5)         R0
C24      22u                               C0603             rcl              (-69.85 63.5)         R0
C25      100n                              C0402             rcl              (-62.23 58.42)        R0
C26      10n                               C0402             rcl              (-74.93 63.5)         R0
C27      100n                              C0402             rcl              (83.15 51.4)          R0
C28      1u                                C0402             rcl              (78.3 50.25)          R180
C29      47uF                              C0603             rcl              (-35.56 53.34)        R0
C30      0.5p                              C0402             rcl              (83.8 46.35)          MR270
C31      100n                              C0603             rcl              (-74.93 58.42)        R0
C32      100n                              C0603             rcl              (-17.78 63.5)         R0
C33      10u                               C0402             rcl              (-16.51 68.58)        R0
C34      120n                              C0603             rcl              (-24.13 63.5)         R0
C34_X5R  >2.2u                             C0402             rcl              (-21.59 53.34)        R0
C34_X5R1 >2.2u                             C0402             rcl              (-80.01 48.26)        R0
C35      10u                               C0402             rcl              (-21.59 68.58)        R0
C36      1u                                C0402             rcl              (83.15 52.45)         R180
C37      6.8n                              C0603             rcl              (-34.29 63.5)         R0
C40      10u                               C0402             rcl              (83.1 42.85)          MR180
C53      1u                                C0603             rcl              (-36.83 68.58)        R0
C54      12p                               C0603             rcl              (-41.91 68.58)        R0
C55      12p                               C0603             rcl              (-46.99 68.58)        R0
C56      100u                              A/3216-18R        rcl              (-66.04 40.64)        R0
C57      100u                              A/3216-18R        rcl              (-71.12 40.64)        R0
C58      100u                              A/3216-18R        rcl              (-76.2 40.64)         R0
D1       PD3S160                           POWERDI323        diode            (-46.99 41.91)        R0
D2       PD3S160                           POWERDI323        diode            (-55.88 41.91)        R0
IC1      OPA333DBV                         SOT23-5           linear           (79.2 48.1)           R90
J1                                         MOLEX_47346-0001  Molex-47346-0001 (-39.37 17.78)        R0
L3       BLM15HD182SN1                     0402              inductors        (-53.34 48.26)        R0
L4       BLM15HD182SN1                     0402              inductors        (-69.85 48.26)        R0
R1       33M                               R0603             rcl              (82.65 46.3)          MR90
R2       10K                               R0402             rcl              (118.85 50.55)        R270
R3       2k2                               R0402             rcl              (-31.75 78.74)        R0
R4       10K                               R0402             rcl              (118.85 40.75)        R270
R5       10k                               R0402             rcl              (-36.83 78.74)        R0
R6       10k                               R0402             rcl              (83.1 43.9)           MR0
R7       10k                               R0603             resistor         (-36.83 48.26)        R0
R8       2k2                               R0402             rcl              (106.4 40.8)          R90
R9       220                               R0603             rcl              (-26.67 78.74)        R0
R10      100                               R0402             rcl              (107.85 43.95)        R90
R11      2k2                               R0402             rcl              (106.4 50.65)         R270
R12      100                               R0402             rcl              (107.85 47.45)        R270
R13      4.7                               R0402             rcl              (81.55 41.65)         R270
R14      47                                R0402             rcl              (115.2 40.75)         R90
R15      2k2                               R0402             rcl              (110.85 40.75)        R270
R16      47                                R0402             rcl              (115.2 50.55)         R270
R17      10k                               R0603             resistor         (-16.51 48.26)        R0
R18      15                                R0603             rcl              (122.15 43.85)        R90
R19      2k2                               R0402             rcl              (110.85 50.55)        R90
R20      10                                R0603             rcl              (122.15 47.5)         R270
R21      10k                               R0603             resistor         (-21.59 48.26)        R0
R22      4.7                               R0402             rcl              (79.95 39.1)          R0
R23      47k                               R0402             rcl              (78.35 51.55)         R180
R24      1k                                R0402             rcl              (77.85 54.05)         R0
R27      1k                                R0402             rcl              (82.6 45.4)           R90
R28      20k                               R0402             rcl              (78.2 45.95)          R0
R29      0.2                               R0603             rcl              (80.4 41.1)           R90
R35      10K                               R0402             rcl              (80.45 50.25)         R0
R36      10k                               R0603             resistor         (-26.67 48.26)        R0
R42      500                               R0603             resistor         (-31.75 48.26)        R0
R48      100                               R0402             rcl              (116.45 40.75)        R90
R49      100                               R0402             rcl              (116.75 50.55)        R90
SOT23-1  LTC6240                           SOT23-5           artinis          (82.3 50.2)           MR180
T1       PMV16UN                           SOT-23            zetex            (121 40.75)           R90
T2       FMMT617                           SOT-23            zetex            (108.6 40.85)         R180
T3       FMMT717                           SOT-23            zetex            (-40.64 25.4)         R0
T4       FMMT617                           SOT-23            zetex            (108.6 50.55)         R0
T5       PMV16UN                           SOT-23            zetex            (121 50.55)           R90
T6       FMMT617                           SOT-23            zetex            (113 40.65)           R0
T8       FMMT617                           SOT-23            zetex            (113.05 50.65)        R180
U$1      BPW34SMD                          BPW_34_SMD        jwasys           (80 45.7)             MR180
U$2      TPS73433                          SOT23-5           artinis          (-48.26 15.24)        R0
U$4      LED760/850_ROITHNER               DUOLED_5MM        jwasys           (110 45.7)            R90
U$5      LED760/850_ROITHNER               DUOLED_5MM        jwasys           (115 45.7)            R90
U$6      LED760/850_ROITHNER               DUOLED_5MM        jwasys           (120 45.7)            R90
U$7      TM4C123GH6ZRBBGA157               BGA_157_MICROSTAR artinis          (-26.67 6.35)         R0
U$8      REF3225                           SOT95P280X100-6N  artinis          (82.95 48.95)         R90
U$10     TPS73633                          SOT23-5           artinis          (-55.88 15.24)        R0
U$12     BNO055LGA-28                      LGA-28            artinis          (-59.69 78.74)        R0
U$14     ECX-42_CRYSTALECS-160-9-42-CKM-TR ECX-42_CRYSTAL    artinis          (-67.31 77.47)        R0
U$16     HEADER_1.27_7                     HEADER_1.27_7     jwasys           (-73.66 77.47)        R0
U1       ADS8860                           SOP50P490X110-10N artinis          (85.3 40.35)          R0
U6       THS4281DBVT                       SOT95P280X145-5N  artinis          (78.85 43.85)         R180
```

Output from code (MagunRa):

```
Part - Value - Package - Amount
['R29'],0.2,R0603,1
['C30'],0.5p,C0402,1
['R20'],10,R0603,1
['R10', 'R12', 'R48', 'R49'],100,R0402,4
['C1', 'C2', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12', 'C14', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20', 'C22', 'C25', 'C27', 'C31', 'C32'],100n,C0402,7
['C1', 'C2', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12', 'C14', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20', 'C22', 'C25', 'C27', 'C31', 'C32'],100n,C0603,11
['C21', 'C56', 'C57', 'C58'],100u,A/3216-18R,4
['R2', 'R4', 'R35'],10K,R0402,3
['R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R17', 'R21', 'R36'],10k,R0402,2
['R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R17', 'R21', 'R36'],10k,R0603,4
['C23', 'C26'],10n,C0402,2
['C5'],10n-1%,C0402,1
['C16', 'C33', 'C35', 'C40'],10u,C0402,4
['C34'],120n,C0603,1
['C54', 'C55'],12p,C0603,2
['R18'],15,R0603,1
['R24', 'R27'],1k,R0402,2
['C3', 'C4', 'C13', 'C15', 'C28', 'C36', 'C53'],1u,C0402,6
['C3', 'C4', 'C13', 'C15', 'C28', 'C36', 'C53'],1u,C0603,1
['R28'],20k,R0402,1
['R9'],220,R0603,1
['C17', 'C24'],22u,C0603,2
['R3', 'R8', 'R11', 'R15', 'R19'],2k2,R0402,5
['R1'],33M,R0603,1
['R13', 'R22'],4.7,R0402,2
['R14', 'R16'],47,R0402,2
['R23'],47k,R0402,1
['C29'],47uF,C0603,1
['R42'],500,R0603,1
['C37'],6.8n,C0603,1
['C34_X5R', 'C34_X5R1'],>2.2u,C0402,2
['U1'],ADS8860,SOP50P490X110-10N,1
['L3', 'L4'],BLM15HD182SN1,0402,2
['U$12'],BNO055LGA-28,LGA-28,1
['U$1'],BPW34SMD,BPW_34_SMD,1
['U$14'],ECX-42_CRYSTALECS-160-9-42-CKM-TR,ECX-42_CRYSTAL,1
['T2', 'T4', 'T6', 'T8'],FMMT617,SOT-23,4
['T3'],FMMT717,SOT-23,1
['U$16'],HEADER_1.27_7,HEADER_1.27_7,1
['U$4', 'U$5', 'U$6'],LED760/850_ROITHNER,DUOLED_5MM,3
['SOT23-1'],LTC6240,SOT23-5,1
['J1'],MOLEX_47346-0001,Molex-47346-0001,1
['IC1'],OPA333DBV,SOT23-5,1
['D1', 'D2'],PD3S160,POWERDI323,2
['T1', 'T5'],PMV16UN,SOT-23,2
['U$8'],REF3225,SOT95P280X100-6N,1
['U6'],THS4281DBVT,SOT95P280X145-5N,1
['U$7'],TM4C123GH6ZRBBGA157,BGA_157_MICROSTAR,1
['U$2'],TPS73433,SOT23-5,1
['U$10'],TPS73633,SOT23-5,1
```

Output I'm trying to get:

```
Part - Value - Package - Amount
[C1,C7,C10,C14,C22,C25,C27],100n,C0402,7
Etc,
Etc,
```

As you can see in the file the part are starting with a letter: C, D, R, L etc..
Is it possible to sort on that so it displays in alphabetic order?

Comment: Please explain last 3 lines of your question. Also change the subject, relavant to your question ,not your brain condition :)

Comment: I'm trying to edit the code so it it gets the first 3 columns and not the 2nd and 3rd column. But when i do this it only displays one value from first column, so my question is how can i get the code to add all "part" value's in front of the output. like "C2,100nF,C0603,8" is in there 8 times, so there should be 8 times "C2, etc, etc".

Comment: @kingAm Thankyou for editing my post, couldn't find the words i wanted to use.

Comment: Not a problem. Please edit your question, wharever you explained in above comment. It will be more clear for others to understand your problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea how @kingAm?

Comment: why are you skipping ten lines? Also how can you get the first three columns and then ignore the second and third column?

Comment: The reason i'm skipping 10 lines is because there is some information about the program that exports the file. Version number etc, all files start from line 11. @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter dict is not the best approach for your problem, if you want to associate the value with the first part you encounter you can use the following approach which use a tuple of `(Value, Package)` as the key and sets the part to the first part we encounter that is associated with the `(Value, Package)` pairing. Using islice is pointless as you are splitting the first three columns so there is no real benefit. Using an OrderedDict will also keep the order of your file:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

d = OrderedDict()
with open('test.txt') as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=["Part", "Value", 'Package', "Amount"])
    wr.writeheader()
    next(f) # skip header
    for line in f:
        a, b, c, _ = line.split(None, 3) # split into three columns
        key = (b, c) # Value and Package is our key
        d.setdefault(key, dict(Amount=0, Part=a, Value=b, Package=c)) 
        d[key]["Amount"] += 1 # increase count every time we see the key
    wr.writerows(d.itervalues()) # DictWriter will handle writing the rows
```

Which outputs:

```
Part,Value,Package,Amount
C1,1nF,C0603,1
C2,100nF,C0603,8
C3,10uF_Tantalum,C0603,1
C4,22uF,C0603,1
C5,1uF,C0603,1
C13,0.22uF,C0603,1
C14,2.2uF,C0603,2
HDR_PRGRM_NIET_PLAATSEN,HEADER_1.27_6P,HEADER_1.27_6,1
L1,MURATA10UH,R1210,1
R1,22K,R0603,2
R3,100,R0603,4
R4,483,R0603,1
R10,10k,R0603,1
R11,10K,R0603,2
R14,19.6K,R0603,1
TP1,PTR1TP20R,TP20R,4
TP5,PTR1PAD1-13Y,P1-13Y,2
U$1,WML-C20,WML-C20,1
U$4,MCP4921-E/MS,SOP65P490X110-8N,1
U$6,TSV912DFN8_2X2,DFN8_2X2,1
U$9,LTC3525_BOOST,SC70-6,1
U1,REG71055DDCT,SOT95P180X110-6N,1
U2,ATMEGA32L-8MU,QFN50P700X700X100-45N,1
X1,53047-05,53047-05,1
```

If you want to keep all the parts and just add the count after each part then keep a list of all parts associated with the `(Value, Package)` pairing instead of just the first and write each Part, Value, Package and Amount iterating over `v["Parts"]` which will hold all the parts associate with particular `(Value, Package)`, to get the file on the original order we need to use a key to sort which will be the line where the part appeared in the file by using a dict to create a mapping from the order we saw the part:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(lambda: dict(Amount=0, Parts=[], Value=b, Package=c))
with open('foo.txt') as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    order = {} # use this later to sort
    wr.writerow(["Part", "Value", 'Package', "Amount"])
    next(f)
    for ind, line in enumerate(f):
        a, b, c, _ = line.split(None, 3)
        order[a] =  ind
        key = (b, c)
        d[key]["Amount"] += 1
        d[key]["Parts"].append(a)
    # flatten the Parts so we can sort back to the original order
    flat = ((k,v["Amount"],v["Value"],v["Package"]) for v in d.itervalues() for k in
            v["Parts"])
    # sort by part
    wr.writerows(sorted(flat, key=lambda x: order[x[0]]))
```

Which outputs:

```
Part,Value,Package,Amount
C1,C0603,1nF,1
C2,C0603,100nF,8
C3,C0603,10uF_Tantalum,1
C4,C0603,22uF,1
C5,C0603,1uF,1
C6,C0603,100nF,8
C7,C0603,100nF,8
C8,C0603,100nF,8
C11,C0603,100nF,8
C12,C0603,100nF,8
C13,C0603,0.22uF,1
C14,C0603,2.2uF,2
C15,C0603,2.2uF,2
C16,C0603,100nF,8
C17,C0603,100nF,8
HDR_PRGRM_NIET_PLAATSEN,HEADER_1.27_6,HEADER_1.27_6P,1
L1,R1210,MURATA10UH,1
R1,R0603,22K,2
R2,R0603,22K,2
R3,R0603,100,4
R4,R0603,483,1
R5,R0603,100,4
R7,R0603,100,4
R10,R0603,10k,1
R11,R0603,10K,2
R12,R0603,100,4
R13,R0603,10K,2
R14,R0603,19.6K,1
TP1,TP20R,PTR1TP20R,4
TP2,TP20R,PTR1TP20R,4
TP3,TP20R,PTR1TP20R,4
TP4,TP20R,PTR1TP20R,4
TP5,P1-13Y,PTR1PAD1-13Y,2
TP6,P1-13Y,PTR1PAD1-13Y,2
U$1,WML-C20,WML-C20,1
U$4,SOP65P490X110-8N,MCP4921-E/MS,1
U$6,DFN8_2X2,TSV912DFN8_2X2,1
U$9,SC70-6,LTC3525_BOOST,1
U1,SOT95P180X110-6N,REG71055DDCT,1
U2,QFN50P700X700X100-45N,ATMEGA32L-8MU,1
X1,53047-05,53047-05,1
```

I would recommend keeping the format like the output above so you can read the files again easily using the csv module.

To get the edited output we only need to change Parts to a list and add all parts:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
from itertools import islice

d = OrderedDict()
with open('test.csv') as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    _ = list(islice(f, 10)) # skip 10 lines
    wr = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=["Parts", "Value", 'Package', "Amount"])
    wr.writeheader()
    for line in f:
        a, b, c, _ = line.split(None, 3) # split into three columns
        key = (b, c) # Value and Package is our key
        d.setdefault(key, dict(Amount=0, Parts=[], Value=b, Package=c))
        d[key]["Amount"] += 1 # increase count every time we see the key
        d[key]["Parts"].append(a)
    wr.writerows(d.values()) # DictWriter will handle writing the rows
```

Output:

```
Parts,Value,Package,Amount
"['C1', 'C7', 'C10', 'C14', 'C22', 'C25', 'C27']",100n,C0402,7
"['C2', 'C6', 'C8', 'C9', 'C11', 'C12', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20', 'C31', 'C32']",100n,C0603,11
"['C3', 'C4', 'C13', 'C15', 'C28', 'C36']",1u,C0402,6
['C5'],10n-1%,C0402,1
"['C16', 'C33', 'C35', 'C40']",10u,C0402,4
"['C17', 'C24']",22u,C0603,2
"['C21', 'C56', 'C57', 'C58']",100u,A/3216-18R,4
"['C23', 'C26']",10n,C0402,2
['C29'],47uF,C0603,1
['C30'],0.5p,C0402,1
['C34'],120n,C0603,1
"['C34_X5R', 'C34_X5R1']",>2.2u,C0402,2
['C37'],6.8n,C0603,1
['C53'],1u,C0603,1
"['C54', 'C55']",12p,C0603,2
"['D1', 'D2']",PD3S160,POWERDI323,2
['IC1'],OPA333DBV,SOT23-5,1
['J1'],MOLEX_47346-0001,Molex-47346-0001,1
"['L3', 'L4']",BLM15HD182SN1,0402,2
['R1'],33M,R0603,1
"['R2', 'R4', 'R35']",10K,R0402,3
"['R3', 'R8', 'R11', 'R15', 'R19']",2k2,R0402,5
"['R5', 'R6']",10k,R0402,2
"['R7', 'R17', 'R21', 'R36']",10k,R0603,4
['R9'],220,R0603,1
"['R10', 'R12', 'R48', 'R49']",100,R0402,4
"['R13', 'R22']",4.7,R0402,2
"['R14', 'R16']",47,R0402,2
['R18'],15,R0603,1
['R20'],10,R0603,1
['R23'],47k,R0402,1
"['R24', 'R27']",1k,R0402,2
['R28'],20k,R0402,1
['R29'],0.2,R0603,1
['R42'],500,R0603,1
['SOT23-1'],LTC6240,SOT23-5,1
"['T1', 'T5']",PMV16UN,SOT-23,2
"['T2', 'T4', 'T6', 'T8']",FMMT617,SOT-23,4
['T3'],FMMT717,SOT-23,1
['U$1'],BPW34SMD,BPW_34_SMD,1
['U$2'],TPS73433,SOT23-5,1
"['U$4', 'U$5', 'U$6']",LED760/850_ROITHNER,DUOLED_5MM,3
['U$7'],TM4C123GH6ZRBBGA157,BGA_157_MICROSTAR,1
['U$8'],REF3225,SOT95P280X100-6N,1
['U$10'],TPS73633,SOT23-5,1
['U$12'],BNO055LGA-28,LGA-28,1
['U$14'],ECX-42_CRYSTALECS-160-9-42-CKM-TR,ECX-42_CRYSTAL,1
['U$16'],HEADER_1.27_7,HEADER_1.27_7,1
['U1'],ADS8860,SOP50P490X110-10N,1
['U6'],THS4281DBVT,SOT95P280X145-5N,1
```

Comment: I am not sure that is the desired output. but you solution is much nicer.

Comment: Very nice what you did here!
But it's not the output i need, the output i want is: C2, C6, C7, C8, C0603,100nF,8.

Comment: @DjordyWinckler, just need to change Parts to a list in the first code

Comment: How do i start from line 10?

Comment: @DjordyWinckler,         `_ = list(islice(f, 10))`

Comment: Damn! Thankyou again so much! Wish i could buy you a cup of coffee!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
cn = Counter(tuple(islice(line.split(), 1, 3)) for line in f)
```

should be

```
cn = Counter(tuple(islice(line.split(), 0, 3)) for line in f)
```

Edit: with updated input file the output is not the desired one:

```
C7,100nF,1
C11,100nF,1
C8,100nF,1
```

Comment: The "Amount" of every component is then "1" because its not the same anymore. And it removes the "package" from the output. Output i want it to be is "[C7, C11, C8],100nF,C0603,3

Comment: Than give a richer example of the component list file. If I copy the line with C2 8 times it works for me.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you list should lookliek

Comment: Added the whole input file.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: That could not work, the count is how many times `Value` and `Package` appear not all three

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not so nice approach:

```
  1 from collections import Counter
  2 from itertools import islice
  3 import sys
  4 
  5 t = open('Componentslist_Count.txt', 'wb')
  6 t.write("Part - Value - Package - Amount")
  7 
  8 def getPartDict(lines):
  9         tmp=[tuple(islice(line.split(), 0, 2)) for line in lines]
 10         for _t in tmp:
 11             if _t[1] in part_dict.keys():
 12                 part_dict[_t[1]].append(_t[0])
 13             else:
 14                 part_dict[_t[1]]=[_t[0]]
 15         return part_dict
 16 
 17 with open('test.txt') as f:
 18         part_dict={}
 19         #f.readline()
 20         f.readline()
 21         _f=f.readlines()
 22         cn = Counter(tuple(islice(line.split(), 1, 3)) for line in _f)
 23         part_dict=getPartDict(_f)
 24         for k, v in cn.items():
 25             t.write("\n")
 26             t.write("{l},{},{},{v}".format(l=part_dict[k[0]],*k, v=v))
```

Output:

```
  Part - Value - Package - Amount
  ['C3'],10uF_Tantalum,C0603,1
  ['X1'],53047-05,53047-05,1
  ['L1'],MURATA10UH,R1210,1
  ['R14'],19.6K,R0603,1
  ['TP5', 'TP6'],PTR1PAD1-13Y,P1-13Y,2
  ['R11', 'R13'],10K,R0603,2
  ['U$6'],TSV912DFN8_2X2,DFN8_2X2,1
  ['HDR_PRGRM_NIET_PLAATSEN'],HEADER_1.27_6P,HEADER_1.27_6,1
  ['R10'],10k,R0603,1
  ['U$9'],LTC3525_BOOST,SC70-6,1
  ['C14', 'C15'],2.2uF,C0603,2
  ['U$4'],MCP4921-E/MS,SOP65P490X110-8N,1
  ['C4'],22uF,C0603,1
  ['R1', 'R2'],22K,R0603,2
  ['U2'],ATMEGA32L-8MU,QFN50P700X700X100-45N,1
  ['C2', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C11', 'C12', 'C16', 'C17'],100nF,C0603,8
  ['U1'],REG71055DDCT,SOT95P180X110-6N,1
  ['C13'],0.22uF,C0603,1
  ['R4'],483,R0603,1
  ['R3', 'R5', 'R7', 'R12'],100,R0603,4
  ['C5'],1uF,C0603,1
  ['TP1', 'TP2', 'TP3', 'TP4'],PTR1TP20R,TP20R,4
  ['C1'],1nF,C0603,1
  ['U$1'],WML-C20,WML-C20,1
```

Comment: Getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    t.write("{l},{},{},{v}".format(l=part_dict[k[0]],*k, v=v))
KeyError: '10uF_Tantalum'

Comment: Not for me, do you have an characters in the input file which are not shown?

Comment: Ahh f**k i see what i didn't tell you, the file starts at line 11.

Comment: is it possible for you to make it start from line 11.

Comment: just put `f.readline()` in line 20 in a loop as you did it with `f.nex()`. Or read the whole file into _f and slice it.

Comment: How does the other file differ? And what goes wrong? The code snippet is only an example. You have to adapt for your problem. If you have files wich differ you have generalize the functions und put in some decisions how to process the different file variations.

Comment: i'm posting other file and output now. There is something going wrong with adding the parts in front of the line.